# How do I stop my Red Nose Pitbull from barking at my neighbors cat?

Tags: dogs, safety, socializing, aggression, vocalizations

My neighbors have a cat that comes into our backyard at night to sleep (so cute) but my meanie Red Nose always goes over to bark at the cat. I understand my dog is trying to protect us but this cat hasn't done *anything* to cause my Red Nose to bark.

I have heard Pitbulls of any kind can easily get very aggressive when people or something bothers them. I've been looking over the internet for someone who had this happen to them like me, but I see only those who talk about how their kids got bitten and things. My dog is beginning to become more and more aggressive every time the cat comes around to sleep in my yard.

How do I stop my Red Nose Pitbull from barking at my next door neighbors cat? Is there a safe way or solution to introducing my dog to my neighbors cat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leave a light on in the house so the dog can't see outside. I doubt your dog can hear or smell the cat (unless your windows are open and it has a bell on its collar). The problem is likely a visual cue. With a light on inside and none on outside, he won't be able to see out of the windows.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to introduce your dog to a cat, you first have to find a cat that gets along with dogs and then have them meet somewhere that's not on your dogs "turf". He will likely be less aggressive if he doesn't think the cat is encroaching on his territory. You must always have him on a leash and have him under control in case he decides to attack the cat.

Try to get your dog to lay down. If he's laying down, he will be less intimidating to the cat, more under control, and less likely to lash out. If you can get him to lay down, that also means that he's at least partially focused on you and not totally fixated on the cat which is already a start.

When they're together, you should reward your dog for good behavior (being calm, sitting or laying down, even just ignoring the cat) and let him know what is bad behavior (barking, chasing, lunging at the cat).

Try to distract him with treats. If he gets used to being around a cat without the cat being the center of his attention, the cat will become less exciting to him.